# What is the meaning of this class?

Tags: java

```
class Drive <String, Integer> {

}
```

What is the meaning of this class with generic return type as string and integer?

Can we make a class as such class definition?

Comment: This is very bad design. It means that `String` and `Integer` in scope of this class will be treated as some unknown generic type (which will prevent us from using for instance `String.format` since compiler will not be able to assume that `String` is `java.lang.String`). It would be better to declare this class as `class Drive <S, I> {...}`

Answer (score 6):

It is a class with two generic types - note that `String` and `Integer` in this case don't have their usual meaning, they are the names of the generic types, hiding the `java.lang.String`.

For example, this would not compile, because `String` in your class is not a usual string:

```
static class Drive <String, Integer> {
  private void m() {
    String s = ""; //incompatible types
  }
}
```

Bottom line, your life would be easier if you stuck to the convention of using single letters, for example:

```
class Drive <T, U> { ... }
```

Comment: What all method types can i include in this class?